# Don't try to correct a command that, now, exists

Tags: zsh, autocorrection

I like zsh's autocorrect for commands. It has an annoying feature, however: sometimes I try to run a command, notice it doesn't exist, install it, then try to run it again, and zsh still wants to make the same correction. Zsh does this because keeps a hash of command paths, and it doesn't go beyond the hash when doing autocorrection. If I say `n` to the correction after installing the command, the command does run, but I have to say `n` again each time I want to run the command, or update the command hash in each running instance by calling the `hash` builtin.

I do want zsh to keep a hash of command paths, and I want to keep autocorrection (i.e. I type a command name and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as usual, and zsh suggests a correction if the command does not exist). However, I want “the command does not exist” to mean that the command is not on `$path` at this point in time, not that the command is does not exist.

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cp /bin/true /tmp/test/wibble
$ PATH=/tmp/test:/bin zsh -f -o correct
darkstar% wobble
zsh: correct 'wobble' to 'wibble' [nyae]? a
darkstar% cp /tmp/test/{wibble,wobble}
darkstar% wobble
zsh: correct 'wobble' to 'wibble' [nyae]? n
```

Desired behavior: when `wobble` exists, don't prompt to correct it. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't experience this on my system. automatically detects `wobble` without action. zsh 5.4.1 on fedora 27. All my \*hash\* options are set to "off".

Comment: @Patrick I have the default settings for all `hash` options, meaning that `hash_list_all`, `hash_cmds` and `hash_dirs` are on.

Comment: @Gilles : I understand that it *should* work in your case, but just for the safe side: Do you see the same effect, if you are doing an explicit `rehash` before trying the autocompletion again?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@user1934428](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/95236/user1934428), you can recreate the hash table explicitly by running `rehash`. To avoid doing it manually put this in your `zshrc`:

`zstyle ":completion:*:commands" rehash 1`

You can find out more about `zstyle` from `zshmodule` man page, and the styles themselves are documented in `zshcompsys`.